# Calculate the ROI when the rate of return has its own rate of change.

Tags: calculus

This is a real-world problem, not a home-work assignment or anything of the sort.

Where I live, the current cost of electricity (Tariff) is $T_0$. Historically, I've noticed that this rate changes at an average compounding monthly rate of $r$. I am installing some solar panels which will generate some average number $n$ of kWhrs each month, which will generate a savings ($S$) of $nT_0$ in the first month.  My solar panels will cost me $c$.

So, in any given month $t$, it would seem my savings would be $nT_t$ or $nT_0(1+r)^t$

I would like to determine an expression which yields the number of months until my accumulated savings equals my initial cost.

Suddenly, I wished I had paid more attention in Calculus class, 28 years ago. I **do** want to remember this stuff, so, showing me the steps/process, not just the answer itself is important to me.

Comment: Where does the -1 in $nT_0[(1+r)^t−1]$ come from?

Comment: Do you mean nT_0[(1+r)^(t-1)] so that the savings from your power generation in month t-1 are realised in month t?

Comment: No, its a typo, the -1 should be removed (I'll do so now)

Comment: I think you need $t-1$ in the exponent, and this does not need calculus.  Have posted in detail below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you meant savings in month $t$ are given by
$$nT_0(1+r)^{t-1}$$
To check, when $t=1$, the first month, the savings are $nT_0(1+r)^{1-1}=nT_0$.

Now to find the cumulative savings till month $M$, we need to sum this up.  Let $S$ denote this savings. So we have
$$S = nT_0 + nT_0(1+r) + nT_0(1+r)^2+...+nT_0(1+r)^{M-1}$$
A simple way to do this sum is to consider multiplying the whole equation above with $(1+r)$.  Then we have
$$S(1+r) = nT_0(1+r) + nT_0(1+r)^2 + nT_0(1+r)^3+...+nT_0(1+r)^M$$

Subtracting the equations, you can notice many terms on the RHS cancelling, giving

$$Sr = nT_0(1+r)^M - nT_0$$
$$\text{or }\quad S = nT_0\frac{(1+r)^M-1}{r}$$

You need to find when this becomes equal to (or greater than) $c$.

So set $\displaystyle nT_0\frac{(1+r)^M-1}{r} = c$ and solve for $M$.  This is probably easier using the actual numbers, however algebraically you could do...

$$(1+r)^M = 1 + \frac{cr}{nT_0}$$
$$M \log(1+r) = \log(1 + \frac{cr}{nT_0})$$
$$\text{So }\quad M = \frac{\log(1 + \frac{cr}{nT_0})}{\log(1+r)}$$

Comment: Excellent work, totally checks out compared to my spreadsheet. Looks like I need brush up on more than my Calculus!

Comment: Ooh! One thing, this equation is undefined when r = 0. No big deal for me, but thought I'd mention it for any future viewers. Thanks again, @Macavity

Comment: @mkoistinen The most interesting case (the one for which the question was answered) is when r>0, and thus the solution contained a geometric series approach which doesn't apply for r=0. Notice if r=0 above, the working doesn't follow, but your problem is much simpler. You just need to find M such that $MnT_0 = c$